# discord.py guild join dmall

Tags: discord.py

I am making a bot to lock all channels when it gets invited ( a lockdown bot )

But I need it to DM all users in the server this is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(ctx, mem):
for mem in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await mem.send("Hello")
        except:
             print('User dm closed')
```

But I get no output and it doesn't DM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated below by Kai, that would be the way to do it. However, due to discord's rate limits (I.E. how fast you can do things, such as send messages), I would suggest adding a cooldown. You will need to `import asyncio` for this to work. Given the except only prints and does not interact with the discord api, you should be fine to only sleep after sending a message.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    members = guild.members
    for member in members:
        try:
            await member.send("Hello")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except:
            print('User dm closed')
```

Comment: That's right, I didn't think about the rate limits. A good idea to do it like this

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because on_guild_join has no member or ctx argument.
on_guild_join has the argument guild, see [discord.on_guild_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_join)
and Guild has the list object members, see [Guild.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members)
Your code could then look like this.

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    members = guild.members
    for member in members:
        try:
            await member.send("Hello")
        except:
            print('User dm closed')
```